# AWS Java NoSuchMethodError using IVONA Text to Speech

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, text-to-speech, nosuchmethoderror

I have started using IVONA TTS and AWS is a dependancy of it, so I have also imported that to the project. My problem is that when running even the sample Java application I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.amazonaws.auth.AWS4Signer.presignRequest(Lcom/amazonaws/Request;Lcom/amazonaws/auth/AWSCredentials;Ljava/util/Date;)V
    at com.ivona.services.tts.IvonaSpeechCloudClient.prepareRequest(IvonaSpeechCloudClient.java:292)
    at com.ivona.services.tts.IvonaSpeechCloudClient.prepareRequestForGetUrl(IvonaSpeechCloudClient.java:270)
    at com.ivona.services.tts.IvonaSpeechCloudClient.getCreateSpeechUrl(IvonaSpeechCloudClient.java:159)
    at filetest.TextToSpeech.main(TextToSpeech.java:49)
```

TextToSpeech.java:49 being:

```
System.out.println("Requested URL: " + speechCloud.getCreateSpeechUrl(createSpeechRequest));
```

I'm using AWS version 1.10.12 (latest), but I've also tried several other previous versions only to get the same error. I've checked the class file "AWS4Signer", and the method "presignRequest" does exist, so I'm confused as to why I'm getting this error. If needed, [here](https://github.com/IvonaSoftware/ivona-speechcloud-sdk-java/blob/master/src/samples/IvonaSpeechCloudCreateSpeech/SampleIvonaSpeechCloudGetCreateSpeechURL.java) is the sample I used.

I'll be happy to add any more information if required. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you executing it from IDE? Which one ?

Comment: Yes, I'm using eclipse

Comment: I've had a look around but I can't find the version number they've used. Should I tried more different versions to see if they work?

Comment: Yes thank you it worked. The earliest I had tried before was 1.9.22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is NoSuchMethod - I suspect that there is a version mismatch. Check from Ivona which version of AWS you need to use. According to Ivona's pom.xml it is 1.9.19.